# Operator Precedence in Conditional Operator

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

So I was experimenting with some templates recently, and this was the code that I stumbled upon:

```
template <typename T>
int someFunction(T someParameter)
{
    return  std::is_same<T, bool>::value ? 1 : 0 +
            std::is_same<T, char>::value ? 2 : 0 +
            std::is_same<T, int>::value  ? 3 : 0;
}
```

So it's basically a bunch of conditional operators that return a value if true, or none at all if false. And if you add them up together, you can determine what data type the argument is.

However, I realized something. Do brackets matter? I tried putting brackets around the code like so:

```
template <typename T>
int someFunction(T someParameter)
{
    return  (std::is_same<T, bool>::value ? 1 : 0) +
            (std::is_same<T, char>::value ? 2 : 0) +
            (std::is_same<T, int>::value  ? 3 : 0);
}
```

But the output is still the same. So I was thinking maybe the compiler sees something like this:

```
template <typename T>
int someFunction(T someParameter)
{
    return  std::is_same<T, bool>::value ? 1 : (0 +
            std::is_same<T, char>::value ? 2 : (0 +
            std::is_same<T, int>::value  ? 3 : 0));
}
```

So in a way, it kind of evaluates the last conditional operator first, and works it's way backwards. But I still can't wrap my head around this thing, and I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly.

Could anyone tell me what's the operator precedence here, and how it's getting executed? Thanks.

Comment: There are references out there for every language that contain an operator precedence table.

Comment: I know that, but I'm confused on the operator precedence for this specific example

Comment: @chris C++ has a language grammar, not a precedence rule  .  Any precedence table is a summary of grammar rules although in the case of the conditional operator it's not a perfect summary

Comment: @M.M, Despite being an abstraction over how the language actually works, it still provides the desired information. The question directly asks "what's the operator precedence here", and that part has a direct answer in a precedence table: `+` is higher than `?:`. Looking for such a table is a quick way to answer that part, C++ or not.

Comment: "Fortunately" for the writer, both interpretations give same results: Only one condition is `true`, adding 0 to condition or final result doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `operator+` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than condition operator, so

```
return  std::is_same<T, bool>::value ? 1 : 0 +
        std::is_same<T, char>::value ? 2 : 0 +
        std::is_same<T, int>::value  ? 3 : 0;
```

is interpreted as

```
return  std::is_same<T, bool>::value ? 1 : 
          ( 0 + std::is_same<T, char>::value ) ? 2 : 
            ( 0 + std::is_same<T, int>::value ) ? 3 : 0;
```

and be more clear

```
return  std::is_same<T, bool>::value ? 1 : 
          ( ( 0 + std::is_same<T, char>::value ) ? 2 : 
            ( ( 0 + std::is_same<T, int>::value ) ? 3 : 0 ) );
```

It'll give the result as `1` for `bool`, `2` for `char`, `3` for `int`.

About `0 + std::is_same<T, ...>::value`, `std::is_same<T, ...>::value` is a `bool`, when used as the operand of `operator+`, it'll be converted to `int` implicitly as `1` for `true`, `0` for `false`. After that the addition result is used as the condition and converted to `bool` back as `false` for `0` and `true` for non-zero.

Comment: How does `( 0 + std::is_same<T, int>::value )` work? `std::is_same` doesn't return a value does it?

Comment: @DynamicSquid, `std::is_same<...>::value` is an integral value. There's also a conversion to said integral value when you use plain `std::is_same<...>{}`.

Comment: @DynamicSquid Answer revised.